# How to switch from Debian 9 Cinnamon's default file-manager "nemo" to another one?

Tags: debian, cinnamon, file-manager

How can I do that? I'd like to switch to [another one](https://wiki.debian.org/FileManager) mainly due to all the bugs I'm encountering with nemo.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [`exo-utils`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/exo-utils) package:

```
apt install exo-utils
```

From the terminal run:

```
exo-preferred-applications
```

Clic on *Utilites* , under *file manager* replace Nemo with your preferred file manager.

Comment: I tried that already. I get `bash: exo-preferred-applications: command not found`. There also is no entry for the file-manager under "Preferred Applications".

Comment: Alright, thank you for your edit. That worked. Strangely it doesn't show "Nemo" in the options for the file-manager. Any idea why that is? Also I can't see any icons on my desktop anymore or right-click it: how can I fix that? And when executing `nautilus` I also get: `(nautilus:18976): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_proxy_new_sync: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed`, "`g_dbus_proxy_get_name_owner: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed` and `PyGIWarning: Nautilus was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Nautilus', '3.0')` (etc). Any help?