# Missing desktop files or folders on Debian 10, but I can see them on file manager

Tags: debian, gnome, desktop

I installed Debian 10 from the minimal installer I downloaded from [this link](https://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/), and I choose the GNOME Desktop Environment. Everything seemed to be fine during the installation.

Now, I found out my desktop has no icons and there is no way to put any kind of file, folder or link in the desktop, but navigating to the desktop trough the file manager correctly shows files and folders.

[image]

This is all I have when I right click on the desktop. 
What could I do to get my desktop icons back?

I already tried to search into `gnome-tweaks` and into the settings for some setting hiding the icons, but I didn't find anything.

I tried solutions posted [on this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377448/desktop-icons-gone-with-nautilus-file-manager-in-debian-9) but it did not work.

Command `gnome-shell --version` outputs `GNOME Shell 3.30.2`

Command `uname -a` outputs `Linux debian 4.19.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-5+deb10u2 (2019-08-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Debian 10 uses [GNOME 3.30](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gnome), did you try searching for ways to do this [with that version](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2018/12/bring-back-desktop-icons-on-gnome-330.html)?

Comment: Are you telling me GNOME has removed the possibility to have icons and folders on desktop? People used desktop for icons and folders for decades, how do I even need a desktop if I can't put stuff on it? I can't believe this a default setting and not some kind of misconfiguration

Comment: Same issue here, with the same gnome version

Comment: It's unbelievable but they removed it, it seems also that they can't make a decent desktop from nautilus: "Also we notice that users rightfully have expectations for the desktop to work decently, and we acknowledge this is far from the reality and we are aware that the desktop is in a very poor state." https://csorianognome.wordpress.com/2017/12/21/nautilus-desktop-plans/

Answer (score 1):

For GNOME Shell 3.30.2 use this extention: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus desktop support has been removed:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/158#instructions.

These are at least 3 solutions:

1. Use `nemo-desktop` instead, `nemo` is a fork from `nautilus`.
   Quote from the above link:

> 1. Install nemo from your distribution's repositories. On Fedora, enter
>    this command on the Terminal application:
>
> `sudo dnf install nemo`
>
> 2. Open a text editor and copy the following text into a new empty file:
>
> ```
>     [Desktop Entry]
>     Type=Application
>     Name=Nemo
>     Comment=Start Nemo desktop at log in
>     Exec=nemo-desktop
>     OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
>     AutostartCondition=GSettings org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons
>     X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
>     NoDisplay=true
> ```
>
> 3. Save the text file as
>    `~/.config/autostart/nemo-autostart-with-gnome.desktop`
>
> And that's it! Next time you log in, nemo will automatically display
> icons over the desktop background. If you don't want to log out, you
> can also manually start it using the Alt+F2 prompt to run nemo-desktop
>
> Optional step: In case you want Nemo to behave more similarly to
> nautilus desktop layout, you can enable the setting running this
> command on the terminal:
>
> `gsettings set org.nemo.desktop use-desktop-grid false`

(On Debian use `apt install nemo`).

On my Debian 10 system I can see that the `AutostartCondition=GSettings org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons` line on the .desktop file doesn't change color as the other on `gedit` (text editor).
I need to remove that part to use it.

2. Use an extension for desktop icons, like this for example: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/.
3. You can use the `desktopfolder` package.

There are also `idesk` and `rox-filer` https://wiki.debian.org/Openbox#Desktop_icons.

I tried `idesk` on gnome it works bad an you have to manually set the icons.
It doesn't reflect the desktop folder.